# How to identify running process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-core, process

**General question:** How to identify a process from a web app running on the same server? Assuming that we start this process from different console app but we can save any data about this process to a database, which is accessible by the web app.

**My specific setup, and more detailed problem description:**

- **Setup:**
  I have a console app - let's call it wrapper. This app is starting a CPU heavy process, let's call it Calculator Process. Wrapper is also saving information about this process to database - a record. I also have a web app - Dashboard - showing information about all running console apps and calculator processes on the server (info taken from the database). When Calculator Process is done, Wrapper is saving finished time to database, and I can show in Dashboard that it has completed.
- **Problem:**
  Sometimes Wrapper dies, and with it the Calculator Process. When it dies, it don't save any information to database, so I am left with a record in unfinished state.
- **Question:**
  How, in Dashbord, identify which unfinished records are the running calculations, and which are just dead leftovers after Wrapper died?
- **Clarifications:** Each Wrapper is started/ended by some external agent. Each Wrapper starts a single Calculator Process. Wrapper is waiting for the process to finish, and then updating a database record, and after that it exits. When Wrapper suddenly dies, then the record is not updated, and the problem emerges.

**Solution that I've tried:**
I've tried saving StartTime of a calculator process into database. Then in Dashboard I've tried to check all running calculator processes by name, get their StartTime from System.Diagnostics.Process class. And my idea was to see which unfinished processes have the same StartTime as the ones that are running. That was I would be able to distinguish running ones from dead ones. But I'm getting:

```
Win32Exception: Access is denied
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(int processId, int access, bool throwIfExited)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(int access, bool throwIfExited)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessTimes()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartTime()
```

Comment: Can you claify what you mean by `When Wrapper suddenly dies`? How does it die?

Comment: @the.Doc - I think, that the same external agent that starts Wrapper, sometimes kills it before it completes. It's outside of my control.

Comment: You could try `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` or `Win32_ProcessEndTrace` to monitor when your process starts/exists. You may need a background thread/proces though, not sure how wmi events work with asp.net. Unless you have access to the server to install as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the end I fixed it by using different way of accessing process data.

```
using System.Management;
```

I used System.Management, to read CreationDate from calculator processes.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTimestampIdOfRunningProcesses(string processName)
{
    var managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
    foreach (var process in managementClass.GetInstances())
    {
        var name = process["Name"].ToString();
        if (name.StartsWith(processName))
        {
            var startTimeText = process["CreationDate"].ToString();
            var startTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(startTimeText);
            yield return startTime.ToTimestampId();
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional details:**

When I start the process I get it's StartTime.

```
public DateTime StartProcess(string path)
{
    using (var process = new SystemProcess())
    {
        process.StartInfo = CreateProcessStartInfo(path);
        process.Start();
        return process.StartTime;
    }
}
```

And then I'm converting it to string in a unified format (using extension method).

```
public static string ToTimestampId(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
}
```

This is my way of unifying data read by System.Management (which has limited precision) and the very precise StartTime that I'm getting at the process start. This way I can compare both values.